# Rearranging the order of the text in a character string in SAS?

Tags: sas, character, text-manipulation

I have a data set with a character variable called "name". It contains the full name  of a person like this:
"firstname middlename lastname".

I want to have the data rearranged so that is becomes:
"lastname, firstname middlename".

I'm not that hardcore in SAS functions, but I have used some of the few I know.

(My code can be seen below).

In the first try (test2) I don't get the result I want - I get:
"lastName , firstName middleName" and not
"lastName, firstName middleName" - my problem is the comma.

So I thought that I would solve my problem by making af new last name variable containing the comma at the end (in test2_new). But I don't get what I want? SAS put three dots at the end, and not a comma?

I hope a person with more SAS skills than me, can answer my question??

Kind Regards
Maria
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
data have ;
  input @1 text & $64. ;
datalines ;
Susan Smith
David A Jameson
Bruce Thomas Forsyth
;
run ;

data want ;
  set have ;
  lastname = scan(text,-1,' ') ;
  firstnames = substr(text,1,length(text)-length(lastname)) ;
  newname = catx(', ',lastname,firstnames) ;
run ;
```

Which gives

```
text                    lastname    firstnames      newname

Susan Smith             Smith       Susan           Smith, Susan
David A Jameson         Jameson     David A         Jameson, David A
Bruce Thomas Forsyth    Forsyth     Bruce Thomas    Forsyth, Bruce Thomas
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this method does not work when you have a middleName variable? I guess then the newname would be: Forsyth, Bruce, Thomas?

Comment: Based on your original post, you don't need an explicit middlename variable, simply to rearrange a single string in the format 'first [middle] last' to 'last, first [middle]'. This method works for any number of middle names, zero upwards.

Answer (score 2):

PERL expressions are a useful tool here, particularly PRXCHANGE.  The SAS Support website provides a good example of how to reverse first and last name, here's a slight modification of that code.  I've only catered for people with either 2 or 3 names, but it should be fairly simple to expand this if necessary.  My code is based on the HAVE dataset created in the answer from @Chris J.

```
data want;
set have;
if countw(text)=2 then text = prxchange('s/(\w+) (\w+)/$2, $1/', -1, text);
else if countw(text)=3 then text = prxchange('s/(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)/$3, $1 $2/', -1, text);
run;
```